# Oracle SQL Query Performance w/ NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, query-optimization

I am attempting to get a list of all client numbers from one of our databases. I only want the clients that have no patients and no billing history.

The query I have works (returns correct results)...but takes ~16hrs to run. I suspect it could be done much more efficiently, but I need some pointers to get me started in the right direction.

```
SELECT A.account_number FROM ClientTable A
WHERE A.account_number NOT IN (SELECT B.account_number FROM PatientTable B) AND
        A.account_number NOT IN (SELECT C.account_number FROM BillingTable C);
```

ClientTable has ~10million rows

PatientTable has ~12million rows

BillingTable has ~25million rows

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 16 hours seems excessive but you have provided us with not enough information to help you. For starters, an explain plan might be useful. Also, do you have indexes on ACCOUNT_NUMBER for all three tables?  What is the datatype of the column on  all three tables?

Comment: As APC stated, that depends. You could experiment with `NOT EXISTS`. I'd rather lean towards altering the process, so the information on if a client has patients or billings would simply be persisted/materialized somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT IN is often expensive. Sometimes a LEFT JOIN and a filter condition can work, but this is dependant on your situation so performance wise I would urge caution, and check your Explain Plan, especially with many rows and tables.

```
SELECT A.account_number 
FROM   ClientTable A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientTable B ON A.account_number = B.account_Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN BillingTable C ON A.account_number = C.account_Number
WHERE B.account_number IS NULL AND C.account_number IS NULL;
```

Comment: This approach completed in under two minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would sets do any good & improvement?

```
(select account_number from clientTable
 minus
 select account_number from patientTable
)
 union    --> optionally, UNION ALL
(select account_number from clientTable
 minus
 select account_number from billingTable
);
```

`UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` should be faster as it wouldn't have to remove duplicates.

Comment: This would actually return incorrect results, i.e. return client accounts which have no patients **or** no billings, instead of client having no patients **and** no billings. To achieve the correct result, using set operators, you would have to select from `clientTable` minus `patientTable` minus `billingTable`. I have no idea on performance of this.